# Impact of changing column Name on indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

If I change a column name, do I need to update my indexes (clustered and non clustered) or I don't have to or SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) does it automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly change index. That will be automatically taken care of.

Comment: i thumb up but if you can give me a document where i can read more of that it would be very helpful, i did not find one on internet

Comment: The index columns are tracked as metadata. That is, the index columns are referenced by column ids, not names. Take a look at the sys.index_columns system view too see that I'm taking about.